# Are Diablo 3 saves stored in the cloud?

Tags: diablo-iii

I hop between computers on a pretty frequent basis, so games that store saves in the cloud (a la Steam Cloud) have been a godsend to me.  Until this point, I've only played Diablo 3 on one computer.

When I switch to another computer, will my save follow me?

Comment: It's actually stored in Hell. :o)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. They must be, in order for you to be able to log in from multiple locations and still have access to your characters.

Comment: Your key-bindings are also stored in the cloud too.

Answer (score 4):

Your character is represented by a database stored on the Battle.Net servers.  Whenever you login, your character is "created" from the information in that database.  So yes, you can login from any computer and access your character.  That isn't quite the same as most games where your save is a file and it can be stored on some "cloud" computer, but it has similar effects.

Answer (score -2):

Well, not for me. it didnt.
Installed on another computer... New game all over again... sigh

Comment: Are you sure? All characters and items are stored on the server as far as I am concerned. This enables things like the auction house to exist in the first place.